# Why constructing a boost::local_shared_ptr is slower than constructing a std::shared_ptr in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, boost

I have the following Google Benchmark:

```
    void SharedPtrUsingNew(benchmark::State & state)
    {
        while (state.KeepRunning())
        {
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(make_shared<MediumSizeData>());
        }
    }
    void LocalSharedPtrUsingNew(benchmark::State & state)
    {
        while (state.KeepRunning())
        {
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(make_local_shared<MediumSizeData>());
        }
    }
```

And also the variation:

```
     void SharedPtrUsingNew(benchmark::State & state)
    {
        while (state.KeepRunning())
        {
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(shared_ptr<MediumSizeData>(new MediumSizeData));
        }
    }
    void LocalSharedPtrUsingNew(benchmark::State & state)
    {
        while (state.KeepRunning())
        {
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(local_shared_ptr<MediumSizeData>(new MediumSizeData));
        }
    }
```

And the results are:

```
Run on (40 X 2195 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32K (x20)
  L1 Instruction 32K (x20)
  L2 Unified 1048K (x20)
  L3 Unified 14417K (x2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                  Time             CPU   Iterations
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SharedPtrUsingNew                        125 ns          126 ns      5600000
LocalSharedPtrUsingNew                   154 ns          157 ns      4480000

2nd variation:
SharedPtrUsingNew                        183 ns          181 ns      3200000
LocalSharedPtrUsingNew                   243 ns          246 ns      2986667
```

This is with boost 1.72 and Visual C++ 2019 16.5.4.

I understand that the benefits of using local_shared_ptr will be that no memory barrier will be used, but I was expecting the construction to be more expensive.

Comment: For the record, incrementing the ref count is almost free:

SharedPtrRefCounting: 18.0 ns; LocalSharedRefCounting: 3.72 ns

Comment: Using make_XYZ inches fewer allocations